# How to make the below python program more memory efficient for large input

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, space-complexity, memory-efficient

This program is to find the number of substrings with at least i distinct letters where 1<= i <= 26 of a string S of length N.

```
def DistinctChars (N, S):
    # Write your code here
    substrings = " ".join((S[i:j] for i in range(N) for j in range(i+1, N+1)))
    for i in range(1, 27):
        if i==1:
            yield len(substrings.split(" "))
        else:
            yield len([item for item in substrings.split(" ") if len(set(item)) >= i])
    
 
N = int(input())
S = input()
 
out_ = DistinctChars(N, S)
print (' '.join(map(str, out_)))
```

*example input*

N=4

A=aabc

*output*

10 6 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

The code is fast as needed and the output is correct. But no matter what I tried, it exceeded the allocated memory of 250MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the memory limit is being exceeded because all `substrings` are being stored in one variable. You could instead define a loop to only pre-compute the values of `len(set(item))` in your code:

```
def DistinctChars (N, S):
    
    all_U = []
    for i in range(N):
        D = set()
        for j in range(i, N):
            D.add(S[j])
            all_U.append(len(D))
    
    for i in range(1, 27):
        yield sum( 1 for n in all_U if n>=i)
```

This approach can save resources exponentially, since all substrings are replaced by only their number of unique characters.

PS. It's actually possible to build an even more efficient algorithm, where the number of substrings with a given number of unique characters is counted immediately. The final answer then corresponds to the cumulative sum of entries with equal or higher number of unique characters:

```
def DistinctChars (N, S):
    
    all_N = [0]*27
    for i in range(N):
        D = set()
        for j in range(i, N):
            D.add(S[j])
            all_N[len(D)] += 1
    
    result = []
    s      =  0
    for i in range(26,0,-1):
        s += all_N[i]
        result.append(s)
    return reversed(result)
```

Comment: But this code snippet didn't output correct answer. I need to parse through the substrings to find whether it contain at least i number of distinct characters. saving the length didn't serve the purpose right.

Comment: Please test the code in your computer before claiming that it does not work. The proposed algorithm outputs the same result as your solution. The array `all_U` (previously called `all_L`) only tracks the number of unique characters found in each substring. The test case that you mentioned with `10 6 1 0 0 ...` actually yields `10 5 2 0 0 ...` when tested with your original code, perhaps that is the source of the confusion. Cheers,

Comment: Please let me know if you need help with other test cases, before marking the proposed solution as accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's working perfectly fine. It's my mistake. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: No problem, thanks to you for the upvote. I updated the answer with a second algorithm, which I realized that is even more memory efficient. I hope you find it interesting :)